# How do i get my file-sharing script to stream uploaded videos?

Tags: php, video, stream, file-sharing

Let's say i have this file-sharing website script but you see, all it
 does is share files, like PutLocker.com , i want it so that if a file
 with an extension like ".mp4 or .mpeg etc" is uploaded, it uses your
 player to stream the file instead of just having shared...

For example:

Jim's wants to start a website, but he is weak at coding. So he gets a
 file sharing script.

But the file-sharing script does just that, share files! Jim wants
 people to be able to stream their video files aswell, and if happy
 worm's player allows him, stream just audio too!

So a user uploads to his website a regular folder, the link is shared,
 the script is working fine. But then a user uploads a .mpeg video and
 Jim does not want his website to just share the file, he wants his
 script to allow users to automatically stream the video file using
 Happy Worm's jPlayer and give users an option to download.

I hope you're not lost, believe me i've read the documentation. Should
 i just slap the player's source code in there or is there some lines
 of code needed to tell it that it needs to stream using that player?

The script i am talking about is X Filesharing pro
 I can link you to the php code i have if it would help better...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

1. PHP runs server-side, it won't play media. (Just like physics, you simply can't.)
2. There are various solutions to deliver media, but the most widely used is Flash.
3. [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) from LongTailVideo is perfect for what you need, both audio and video. 
   The documentation is comprehensive and the player itself has lots and lots of cool extras, such as:

   - buffering
   - a JS API (for HTML styling)
4. For thumbnails from video files you'll need third party tools (ffmpeg) installed on the server, some degree of technical knowledge and access to the exec() function in PHP so you can run command-line tools via PHP and output results.

Comment: So do i take JWPlayer's source code and slap it into the PHP's Home.php page?